# Adjusting the height of the UITextField with editing using iOS Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, autolayout

How do we increase the height of `UITextField` while editing using autolayout. I have a `UIScrollView` with four `UITextField's`. Currently all the textfield's are all of constant height. I need only a particular textfield to grow its height based on the text while editing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to  set height  constrain for each  text field.

And  on edit did end method  you  need to identify  the textfield by tag  and than change the constant of the appropriate textfield.

for ex. heightTxt1,heightTxt2,heightTxt3,heightTxt4  are constraint.

Than change while edit did end called for textfield 1

```
   heightTxt1.constant= (count height on the basis of text and font style,size);
```

This should resolve your issue,

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Set no of lines in your label as 0

[image]

**Step 2:** Add this method in your class file

```
//-- Dynamic label frame depend on text 
-(CGRect)getLabelHeightForIndex:(UILabel *)label label_string:(NSString *)label_string
{
    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, 999);
    CGRect contentFrame;
    CGSize contentStringSize;
    NSString *version = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    NSString *contentStr = label_string;

    if ([version floatValue] < 7.0)
    {
        contentStringSize = [contentStr sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];
    }
    else
    {
        NSDictionary *contentDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:label.font, NSFontAttributeName, nil];
        contentStringSize = [contentStr boundingRectWithSize:maxSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:contentDic context:nil].size;
    }
    contentFrame = CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x, label.frame.origin.y, label.frame.size.width, contentStringSize.height);
    return contentFrame;
}
```

**Step 3:** Access dynamic frame for label using following code

```
//-- Get dynamic label height from given string
    CGRect contentFrame = [self getLabelHeightForIndex:Label label_string:Label.text];
    Label.frame = contentFrame;
    CGFloat LabelHeight = contentFrame.size.height;
```

Comment: No problem. Just replace uilabel into uitextfield in that method.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you will want to store the height constraint for that specific `UITextField` in a property.

For example: `@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *specificTextFieldHeightConstraint;`

Then, implement `-[UITextFieldDelegate textFieldDidBeginEditing:]` inside your `UIViewController` subclass:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    specificTextFieldHeightConstraint.constant = expandedHeightGoesHere;
}
```

Finally, you probably want to return the height back to normal by implementing `-[UITextFieldDelegate textFieldDidEndEditing:]` inside your `UIViewController` subclass:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    specificTextFieldHeightConstraint.constant = originalHeightConstant;
}
```

*If you set equal heights constraints across all of the `UITextFields`, you will need to set the priority of the equal height constraint that is attached to `specificTextField` to low when editing, and set it back to high when editing ends. You will still need a height constraint on `specificTextField`, but it should have a lower priority than the equal height constraint when `specificTextField` is not editing, and it should have a higher priority than the equal height constraint when `specificTextField` is editing.*

Comment: OP asks how to expand the text field **based on the text**. This  answers half of the question though.